# How to array table heading Vertically in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a table of *Projects*, displaying two columns, and one row per *Project*.  I want to display the *Projects* as two rows, and one column per *Project*.

**Current**

```
Project ID | Project Name | 
-------------------------
value1.1   |   value1.2   |
value2.1   |   value2.2   |
...
valueN.1   |   valueN.2   |
```

**Desired**

```
Project ID   | value1.1 | value2.1 | ... | valueN.1
Project Name | value1.2 | value2.2 | ... | valueN.2
```

**component.html.ts**

```js
<div class="card my-5">
  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Project ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Project Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let project of project_list">
          <td>{{ project.id }}</td>
          <td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/admin-pd/', project.id]">
                {{ project.projectname }}
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to change JSON in such way to achieve this

Comment: Use css `display:flex` property

Answer (score 0):

To create a table with a N number of columns, the array of Projects must be iterated over for every property.  In your case there are six properties: Project ID, Project Name, Status, Task, Bug, and Department.

```js
<div class="card my-5">
  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <th>Project ID</th>
          <td *ngFor="let project of project_list">{{ project.id }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Project Name</th>
          <td *ngFor="let project of project_list">
            <a [routerLink]="['/admin-pd/', project.id]">
              {{ project.projectname }}
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Project Status</th>
          <td *ngFor="let project of project_list">{{ project.projectstatus }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Task Associated</th>
          <td *ngFor="let project of project_list">{{ project.TaskAssociated }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Bug Associated</th>
          <td *ngFor="let project of project_list">{{ project.BugAssociated }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Department</th>
          <td *ngFor="let project of project_list">{{ project.Department }}</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if there are multiple properities?

Comment: @GamingwithRoman More than Id, and Name ? Do you have the list of columns before hand?  Each property will need an *ngFor loop.

Comment: I have project_id, projectname, projectstatus, TaskAssociated, BugAssociated,Department